# How do I get a Cassandra node to show the IPv4 address in the nodetool status output?

Tags: nosql, cassandra

I'm currently working on a cluster with DataStax Enterprise 6.8, but the address part of the picture is showing up as localhost (`127.0.0.1`).

How can I get it to show the actual IPv4 address?

[image: Current Status]

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have left the default configuration which means that the DSE process defaults to listening for requests on `localhost` in `cassandra.yaml`.

The `listen_address` is used for private node-to-node (internode) communication so on multi-NIC servers, this is set to the node's IP address.

Clients (applications) connect to DSE nodes on the `native_transport_address` so this is set to a public IP address that clients can reach.

In `cassandra.yaml`, set:

```
listen_address: private_ip
native_transport_address: public_ip
```

For servers which only have one network card, you can set both properties to the same IP address. Cheers!

Comment: I have DSE6.8 on each of my 3 machines using Virtual box, and I had PriateIP in all those 2 settings in cassandra.yaml, so I will try it. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Erick
One unit started up fine, but when I brought up the second unit it did not connect properly, I got an error saying Connect Refused.
Anything else I should be aware of? The seed node has a private IP of node1.
It is a virtualbox so the public IP is common.